# How to allow only PutObject permissions on specific directory in Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, coffeescript, amazon-iam

I am trying to configure an Amazon IAM user with a policy that allows them to only perform uploads to a specific folder of an s3 bucket.

I can successfully upload images when the policy is written like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Put*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

My upload function (in coffeescript with browser side javascript aws-sdk):

```
s3.putObject data, (err, data) =>
  if err
    console.log err
    console.log 'Error uploading data: ', data
  else
    console.log 'succesfully uploaded the image!'
```

However I would like to scope the permissions to only allow putObject, and only in a specific directory. I thought this policy would work, but it throws a 403 error:

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "s3:PutObject"
                ],
                "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/example_directory"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Is there a syntax error in my policy, or am I doing something else incorrectly? I am still new to writing IAM policies.

**Update**

I've made some progress by getting the following code to work in the IAM simulator, but unfortunately it still throws a 403 error when I try to actually upload despite saying that putObject should be allowed.

[image: simulator pass]

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "s3:PutObject*"
                ],
                "Resource": "*"
            },
            {
                "Effect": "Deny",
                "Action": [
                    "s3:PutObjectAcl*",
                    "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl*"
                ],
                "Resource": "*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: can you add `"Principal": "*",` (or the IAM account that you want to restrict) in your policy and retry

Comment: Thanks for your help, I get an error when I do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally got this working as expected, the key was that I had to use `NotAction` and `NotResource` in the `Deny` section.

See the following code:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/myfolder",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/myfolder/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotAction": [
                "s3:PutObjectAcl*",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl*"
            ],
            "NotResource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/myfolder",
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/myfolder/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/example_directory/*"
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it doesn't work - maybe this has something to do with my bucket name being in the format `www.bucketname.com`?

Comment: No that shouldn't matter at all. To clarify, are you getting an error trying to save the policy? Or are you getting an error when you try to put an object after applying the policy?

Comment: I see you changed the working policy from `Put*` to `PutObject`. I think that may be part of the problem. Try changing it back to `Put*` or adding the `s3:PutObjectAcl` permission.

Comment: The policy validates successfully, but it causes the putObject to be denied when I try to upload, in the policy simulator as well as from the browser. The same is true when I use Put* instead of just PutObject.